# calling web services from UNIX

Tags: web-services, unix, salesforce

I have a requirement to kickoff a workflow which is in salesforce.com thorugh web service from UNIX box. Can any one suggest me options or guide lines to achive this scenario?

Comment: What tools and knowledge do you have available? Do you know `curl`, for example?

Comment: Have you checked the link to Integration tools? If you need something that works in Perl: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Web_Services_API#Perl I'm still confused with the use of the "workflow" word though, do you really mean these: http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_workflow_rules.htm or something different?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just "kick off workflows". You'll have to perform an insert or update of records in Salesforce that will satisfy the workflow's entry criteria.

There's a Java tool called [Data Loader](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader) for your basic data manipulation activities (you can download it from your own production org)
and it can be scripted for scheduled runs, has config file where you can store user's password in secure way etc. Check out the [pdf guide](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf) for more ("Command Line Quick Start" chapter)

So I don't think you really need a webservice call...

---

Unless I misunderstood and you're talking about calling an Apex class' method that has "webservice" keyword and it will somehow perform the updates?

In that case you'll need to download the WSDL file generated for this class (Setup->Develop->Classes) and well, consume it in language of your choice (Java, PHP, Python... [this link](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/cookbook/Content/api_setup_intro.htm) will help, steps aren't too different), then do your command line magic?

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Integration has tons of resources for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce uses SOAP for their web service. They don't have restful web services now. Just request them to give the wsdl file.
Use this wsdl file to generate the java code. After that get their webService url so that you can proceed with your  data pulling
This link may help you..

http://salesforce-walker.blogspot.in/2011/12/to-access-salesforce-data-from-java-we.html

Hope this helps

Comment: I have the WSDL file provided by slaesforce team, and that wsdl file has the requests realted to a particular salesforce workflow. Now I seeking help in how to call that wsdl file from Perl/UNIX and kick off that salesforce workflow. I shoulf not use any Java